# understanding the limit of a composite function

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & -1 \le x \le 1 \\
10 & x \gt 1  \\
10 & x \lt -1 
\end{cases}$

g(x) = $\sin\frac 1x$

What happens at this limit?
$\lim_{x\to 0}{{(f \circ g}})$

Do I have a discontinuity point? If I divide to the $0^+$ and $0^-$ I get sin(infinity). Does it even matter if the function is bounded?

Comment: any way as you defined  you have $f\circ g = 1$ since $-1\le g\le 1$

Comment: I understand now. The limit will be 1. What about the point itself, I'm assuming it's undefined and we have a removable discontinuity point. Is that right?

Comment: which removable point are you talking about? 0 I suppose we don't care as on the right and on the left the function is valued at one

Answer (score 2):

For $x \ne 0$ we have $ -1 \le g(x) \le 1$, hence $(f \circ g)(x)= 1$

Your turn !

Comment: I'm aware of this. I'm asking what happens at the limit when x tends to zero of the composed function? Because If I to the limit of $0_+$ then the value inside my sin function becomes infinity. How does this affect f(x)?

Comment: We have (f \circ g)(x)= 1 for all $x \ne 0$, hence $ \lim_{x\to 0+}(f \circ g)(x)=1= \lim_{x\to 0-}(f \circ g)(x)$

Comment: Ahh yes you're right. But the point 0 itself is not defined in the composed function, right? This means we have a removable discontinuity at 0?